# Watch for addition of a referenced library to a project (Visual Studio 2008 plug-in)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, plugins, reference

I am hoping someone can help me with this. What I have been looking around for but can't seem to find is if there is someway to add an event, or anything else that will allow a visual studio plug-in to watch for an external reference to be added to a currently open solution / project?

Or even better yet would anyone happen to know of an add-in that automatically adds all controls from a referenced dll into the visual studio toolbox?

Thanks.

Comment: That would be nice.  I feel like I'm missing something on how controls from referenced dlls should work.  My searching has just started... so I'll chime in here if I find something.

Comment: On the point about things being automatically added into the toolbox... Which version of Visual Studio 2008 are you using? (Professional? Standard? Express? )

Comment: I'm using VS 2008 Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked, but I've written a Visual Studio 2008 Integration Package, and if I recall correctly I could override the "add reference" method, as well as inherit the "reference node" and thus change its behavior, for example its constructor.

This functionality might be missing from an add-in (which is more limited than an integration package), so you might consider writing a package instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a macro that will change a file reference to a project reference if you add the project to the solution (and vice versa), but I don't think that's what you want?

Comment: I would love to have that feature. We buy the source for a large UI framework and I have to spend several hours linking up all the projects to build our customized libraries from it.

Comment: Ask the question, and leave me a comment on one of my questions with a link to your question (pending implementation of a viable way to contact other users)